# Issue with using the antbuilder mail task in groovy 1.7.2

Tags: ant, groovy, email

I recently have a problem using the antbuilder mail task in groovy. It always throws the following exception:

> [mail] Sending email: null
>
> [mail] Failed to send email: 0
>
> Caught: : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I think the problem just occurred with the release of the new 1.7.2 version, but I cannot be sure of it.

Here is the snippet:

```
ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.mail(mailhost:'localhost',mailport:'25',subject:'Hello Ant World',messagemimetype:'text/html') {
 from(address:'changed@to.protect.the.innocent')
 to(address:'changed@to.protect.the.innocent')
 message('Hello ant world!')
}
```

Any idea how to get this working? 
Thanks, Ingo

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was that i had GroovyWS in my classpath. See: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GMOD-55

Comment: Please add relevant content from that link to your answer here. Consider what would happen the usefulness of your answer if the link became broken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are absolutely right. By just removing that jar it works. Thanks. But since I use the groovyws lib I had to work it out with plain javax.mail code...